# GraphQL: Overriding slugs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I'm starting my first project with Gatsby and have run into an issue with querying data that "may" not always exist. Here is my `gatsby-node.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const _ = require('lodash');

// Lifecycle methods

function attachFieldsToBlogPost({ node, actions }) {
  if (node.internal.type !== 'MarkdownRemark') {
    return;
  }

  const { createNodeField } = actions;

  const { slug, title } = node.frontmatter;
  const postPath = slug || _.kebabCase(title);

  createNodeField({
    node,
    name: 'slug',
    getter: node => node.frontmatter.slug, // eslint-disable-line no-shadow
    value: postPath,
  });

  createNodeField({
    node,
    name: 'url',
    value: postPath,
  });
}

exports.onCreateNode = function() { // eslint-disable-line func-names
  return Promise.all([attachFieldsToBlogPost].map(fn => fn.apply(this, arguments))); // eslint-disable-line prefer-rest-params
};

// Implementations

function getMarkdownQuery({ regex } = {}) {
  return `
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
        filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "${regex}" } }
      ) {
        totalCount
        edges {
          node {
            fileAbsolutePath
            excerpt(pruneLength: 280)
            timeToRead
            frontmatter {
              title
              date
              slug
            }
            fields {
              url
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;
}

function createBlogPostPages({ edges, createPage }) {
  const component = path.resolve('src/templates/Post.js');

  edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    const { slug, title } = node.frontmatter;
    const postPath = slug || _.kebabCase(title);

    createPage({
      path: postPath,
      component,
      context: {
        slug: postPath,
      },
    });
  });
}

exports.createPages = async({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const results = await Promise.all([
    graphql(getMarkdownQuery({ regex: '/src/posts/' })),
  ]);

  const error = results.filter(r => r.errors);
  if (error.length) {
    return Promise.reject(error[0].errors);
  }

  const [blogPostResults] = results;

  const { createPage } = actions;
  const blogPostEdges = blogPostResults.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges;

  createBlogPostPages({
    createPage,
    edges: blogPostEdges,
  });
};
```

And my example blog post content is:

````
---
title: 'Hello world there'
date: '2018-08-25'
---

Here is some content.

```javascript
console.log('test')
```
````

When I supply a `slug` frontmatter component, the page is created as intended. But, I'd only like to use the `slug` parameter when it's available (hence the check to see if the frontmatter is available in both `attachFieldsToBlogPost` and `createBlogPostPages`). If I remove the `slug` frontmatter item, I get the following error:

`GraphQLError: Cannot query field "slug" on type "frontmatter".`

Is there a way to override the path used to create the post pages "if" the `slug` frontmatter is there?

Hopefully this isn't too vague as it's my first Gatsby project, but seems like a pretty useful feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove every case of `slug` then the field will no longer exist in Gatsby's internal schema. You're probably running into [the issue described here](https://www.gatsbycentral.com/gatsby-ignores-empty-fields).

So long as you have at least 1 markdown file with a `slug` field, then it will exist in Gatsby's automated GraphQL schema, and then your conditional logic should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Makes total sense. I came across that as well and realized I should probably just go the route of creating a "blueprint" file, and then just remove that from what is actually parsed/used to create pages. I guess just a bit funky for how I'm used to querying data, but am new to GraphQL. Thanks again!

Comment: Not just you, it's definitely funky. Any kind of automatic schema generation will always run into this type of problem, and manually generating schemas would add a ton of work for very little gain...